# Delete row contains image and multi foreign key in table in database using AJAX- ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to delete row in my table (Cars) using Ajax so that the page does not refresh when I try to delete the row of the table. Here is the code I have, but at the moment pressing Delete does nothing:

Table(Cars):
id
image
BodyId (FK)
GearBoxId (FK)
OfficeId (FK)

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(string id)
    {
        Cars cars = await db.Cars.FindAsync(id);
        db.Cars.Remove(cars);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Json("");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteCarImage(string id, string 
     imageId)
    {
        Cars cars = await db.Cars.FindAsync(id);
        cars.Images = cars.Images?.Replace(imageId + "*", "");
        db.Entry(cars).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/images/cars"), 
         imageId));
        return Json("");
    }
```

View:
     Delete

Script:

```
   <script>
    function deleteCar(id)
    {
      swal({
      text: "You will not be able to recover this car !!",
      type: "warning",
      howCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it !!",
      cancelButtonText: "No, cancel it !!",
      closeOnConfirm: false,
      closeOnCancel: true,
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true},
      function (isConfirm)
      {
        if (isConfirm){
         $.ajax({
         method: 'POST',
         url: '/Cars/Delete/' + id,
         success: function (response)
         {
           var row = document.getElementById(id);
           row.remove();
           swal("Deleted", "Car have been deleted.", "success");
         },
        error: function (error){sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went 
        wrong!!","error");}
                });
                       }
       });   
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Does the post request result succeed or fail? Can you provide more details?

Comment: It's fail. The result was only the message "Oops..something went wrong" , but after i tried to edit the code by using get request and add delete view it's always fail. So i returned to the post request.

Comment: url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}" This is my routes.

Comment: What is the Http Response Status Code 500 or 404 ? You can use the Browser Network Inspector (F12) to see this. If the result is 404, it means that MVC cannot find the method you are calling, Putting the `RouteAttribute`: `[Route("Cars/Delete/{id}")]` on the Delete function may solve the issue. Best practices is to use the good Verb for Deletes. You should use `method:'DELETE', url:'/Cars/' + id` and the HttpVerb on the controller function should Also be `[HttpDelete][Route("/Cars/{id}")]`

Comment: The status is 404. The error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" Cars:479.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. I have these errors:                                          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
linea.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
flag-icon.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
materialdesignicons.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Cars:479 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
weather-icons.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
linea.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
flag-icon.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
materialdesignicons.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: When i put @item.id in quotes <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat   btn-danger" onclick="deleteCar('@item.Id')">Delete</button> the result is always error status.

Comment: I use    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-flat   btn-danger" }) and got this error: Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Cars/Delete/45BEFA3B0A6E45328B72400D2E0D852D

Comment: Can you put in the question the entire controller class? 404 means the route is not found

Comment: namespace CarProject.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Employee")]
    public class CarsController : BaseController
    {
        // GET: Cars
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var cars = db.Cars.Include(c => c.Brands).Include(c => c.Offices);
            return View(await cars.ToListAsync());
        }

Comment: // POST: Cars/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Cars cars)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                cars.Id = GUID();
                db.Cars.Add(cars);
                for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                {

Comment: var file = Request.Files[i];
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = cars.Id + GUID() + file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/images/cars"), fileName);
                        cars.Images += fileName + "*";
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                    }

Comment: }
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.BodyId = new SelectList(db.Bodies, "Id", "Name", cars.BodyId);
            ViewBag.BrandId = new SelectList(db.Brands, "Id", "Name", cars.BrandId);
            ViewBag.GearboxId = new SelectList(db.Gearbox, "Id", "Name", cars.GearboxId);
            ViewBag.OfficeID = new SelectList(db.Offices, "Id", "City", cars.OfficeID);
            return View(cars);
        }

Comment: // POST: Cars/Delete/5
        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("/Cars/{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(string id)
        {
            Cars cars = await db.Cars.FindAsync(id);
            db.Cars.Remove(cars);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Json("");
        }

Comment: // POST: Cars/Delete/5
        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("/Cars/{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteCarImage(string id, string imageId)
        {
            Cars cars = await db.Cars.FindAsync(id);
            cars.Images = cars.Images?.Replace(imageId + "*", "");
            db.Entry(cars).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/images/cars"), imageId));
            return Json("");
        }

Comment: protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CarSelling.Models;
using System.IO;

Comment: The Global asax :namespace CarProject
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);         }
    }
}

Comment: Did you changed the ajax call to use delete verb? ... `method: 'POST', url: '/Cars/Delete/' + id,` ... by `method: 'DELETE', url: '/Cars/' + id,`

Comment: Yes i did. I  changed the ajax call to use delete verb

Comment: Do you have other call that works?

Comment: Yes i have , the same call in other control class and the request always succeed.